# Overriding single property setter from ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf

I have a style defined in a file called MyStyles.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
    <EventSetter Event="CellUpdating" Handler="grid_CellUpdating"/>
</Style>
```

In one of my views, I have a XamDataGrid defined:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid>
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject.TheViews;component/Views/MyStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}}">
          <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="70"/>
        </Style>
      </ResourceDictionary>
     </igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
```

Basically, I want to keep everything that is defined in the style for XamDatagrid in MyStyles.xaml except for the font size, which I want to be set to 70.

I can't seem to get it to work.  With the above, the font is set to 70 but I lose the other settings that are defined in MyStyles (such as the event handling and font family).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As a workaround, maybe you can try this: in MyStyles.xaml: `<Style x:Key="LALALA">...</Style>  <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource LALALA}"/>`; in the view: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}">  BasedOn="{StaticResource LALALA}"> ...`

Comment: And, if you are already inside `XamDataGrid`, why not just simply use `FontSize="70"` for the `XamDataGrid` itself? It will override the settings from style.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this without taking either of Vlad's suggestions, basing on the type itself will return you the default style of the control.

Comment: @Vlad: When using a key for the style, it works as expected. However, in this view (and others), there are multiple grids that each use MyStyles.xaml.  If I add a key to the specific style, the other grids don't automatically pick it up.  What I was trying to do is somehow set a new style for in single view (for example at UserControl.Resources) where all of the grids in that view inherit the style from MyStyles and override the font size.  That way if I need to change the font size again, I only need to change it in one place.

Comment: Well, I see. But have a look, there is a default style defined in MyStyles, based on LALALA (I refer to the 1st suggestion above), so this way must do.

Comment: @Vlad: If you add your comments as an answer I can select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Extracting an answer from comments above.)

For overriding the style, I would suggest the following:

Define 2 styles in `MyStyles.xaml`: a named one which contains the style, and the unnamed one (this will be the default style) simply based on the named one

```
<Style x:Key="XamDataGridDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
    <EventSetter Event="CellUpdating" Handler="grid_CellUpdating"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource XamDataGridDefaultStyle}"/>
```

This will define the needed default style for all the views.

For the resources of the view where the customization is needed, define the following override:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource XamDataGridDefaultStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="70"/>
</Style>
```

You'll perhaps need to reference `MyStyles.xaml` as merged dictionary in the resources of the customized view for `StaticResource` to work.